# Error while running DDA Line drawing algorithm in C

Tags: c, vector-graphics, bgi, dda

I wrote a code to implement DDA line drawing algorithm in C. The line always generated on the top left corner and very thin,i want the line to be in the middle of the screen. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?
My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
    int x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,temp;
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);    
    printf("Enter the x1,y1:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x1,&y1);
    printf("Enter the x2,y2:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x2,&y2);
    int dx=abs(x2-x1);
    int dy=abs(y2-y1);
    if(dx>dy)
    {
        temp=dx;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=dy;
    }
    float xin=dx/temp;
    float yin=dy/temp;
    x=x1;
    y=y1;
    for(int k=0; k<temp; k++)
    {
        x=x+xin;
        y=y+yin;
        putpixel(x,y,RED);
        delay(100);
    }
getch();
closegraph;
}
```

I have also attached an image of the output.[image]

Comment: Did you use a debugger and step-by-step execution, to see exactly the values of all the data in the program? That might give you important clues about what is going on.

Comment: `i want the line to be in the middle of the screen` - what is the screen size you assume/expect? What is the screen size from the point of view of the library? Please note that they might be different. You have very small input numbers, compared with the e.g. FULL-HD resolution, 1920x1080. Try numbers in the range of hundreds, and see what happens.

Comment: Great! What did you do, how did you make it work?

Comment: @virolino nothing much,as you said i gave the numbers more than 100 and the output automatically came to the center.

Comment: Aha. OK. I was not sure which of my hints helped.